# c++ - reference the last field of a struct without it taking any space

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

Using c++23,

I have a large memory frame which has a header gathering some info on it.

So the layout is Main + repetitions of structs Other afterwards.
is there a modern way to express this, without s taking any space?

```
struct Other{

    int a;
    int b;

};

struct Main {

    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    Other s; <- this one

};
...
Main *m = std::bit_cast<Main*>(addr_ptr);
...
span <Other> sp {&m->s, some_length};
```

The current solution is to have a dummy struct defined that way:

```
struct Main {

    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;

};
struct Main_full {

    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    Other s;

};
```

and cast as appropriate.

But is there a clean and modern way to express this in C++23, without having to cast ?

`[[ no_unique_address ]]` with an empty class didn't work, but it is something in that vein I would like to find.

It is just for the expressiveness of the code (subjective, but it is what I am after).

Thanks

Comment: When you say "without having to cast" is that including the `std::bit_cast<Main*>` in your example?

Comment: Is `some_length` constexpr?

Comment: There is not really any language support for doing this exactly the way you intend to. In C99 you can add an empty array as the last member of your struct, but not in C++. Why can't you use the span `sp` to access the data?

Comment: @chrysante: no obligation by any means, it is just to make sure I didn't miss a language feature that could do that :)

Comment: @Caleth: some_length can be constexpr yes, because the structures are known at comile time. For the cast, it is just an example of what is done and that I would like to avoid. This question is just for "cosmetic" purposes :)

Comment: I don't think there's any way of avoiding a cast, but I would do it as `std::bit_cast<Other*>(addr_ptr + sizeof(Main))`

Comment: @Caleth, yes sure, this is about what we do with the spans currently (not exactly, about). a [[ placeholder ]] attribute would have been nice to have as it helps expressing clearly what is going on. Just my opinion of course.